# How do I get PHP 7.1 to talk to PostgreSQL on RHEL 7?

Tags: postgresql, php-7.1, rhel7

Running a Laravel installation on a RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 server using PHP 7.1.  I can see `php-pgsql.x86_64` listed in the available yum packages, but it doesn't appear to be compatible with PHP 7.1 (and indeed is listed as version 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1).

On a lark, I tried installing it anyway and physically moved the `pgsql.ini` and `pdo_pgsql.ini` files from `/etc/php.d` into the relevant PHP 7.1 folder `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php71/php.d/` (and did the same with the .so files they reference), but that returns an error indicating that the package couldn't be read (`undefined symbol: file_globals_id in Unknown on line 0`).

Has anyone managed to get PHP 7.1 talking to PostgreSQL on RHEL 7?

Comment: A sysadmin coworker put me onto https://ius.io/ as a possibility. Installing the RHEL7 repo there does improve my `yum search` results:

`php71u-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP`

Going to give this a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sysadmin who originally created the server for me set me straight.  The problem was I was looking in the wrong repository for the packages I needed for my particular PHP installation.  Running the following two commands did the trick:

`sudo yum install --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl rh-php71-php-odbc`

`sudo yum install --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl rh-php71-php-pgsql`

We then added those two packages to the Ansible playbook so future generations would not suffer needlessly.